# What does 停车期间热浸 mean?

Tags: translation

I was going through some papers and I'm stuck on this 热浸. Each dictionary says it means "hot dipping", but how can i hot dip a parked car, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this seems relevant （http://exa-china.com/key-off--soak.html）:

> 其中一个最极端的恶劣工况叫做“停车”或者“热浸”，这是指汽车在发动机很热的情况下很快停车，因为没有了冷却气流，发动机舱内的零件温度会升高。(1)

I think you are getting this sentence here (http://chinabidding.mofcom.gov.cn/govmain.jhtml?method=detail&channelId=205&docid=223065243):

> 测定由于昼夜温度波动、停车期间热浸和城内运转所产生的污染物 (2)

The correct translation for the concept in (1) should be "hot soak": http://esa21.kennesaw.edu/activities/smog-cars/doe-veh-pollutants.pdf

Hopefully (2) is the correct context.  In general it would be good to include at least the entire parent sentence, so we can help you.

Comment: it is this content, thank you very, very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Figuratively speaking, the short time you have before being immersed into a rather hot bath of zinc or other fluid.

Comment: but what about 停车时间热浸， probably not hot bath of zink

Comment: Figuratively speaking.